# Download image then use it in listView using AsyncTask is not working

Tags: android

I want my app to check if there are images available offline then use them in `listView` else download new then use those..

I am getting this error in Logcat

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.nishant.book/files/-KoIyV6QfLGC3J0u‌​MAwo.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I am instantiating this `AvatarLoader` class in my `customAdaper` as

```
new AvatarLoader(context, holder.avatar, userID).execute(rawUrl);
```

Here is my code..

```
public class AvatarLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Context context;
    private ImageView view;
    private String userID;

    public AvatarLoader(Context context, ImageView view, String userID){
        this.view = view;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){
        Bitmap image = null;
        String fileName = userID + ".png";
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            if (inputStream == null){
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
                OutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(inputStream.read());
                outputStream.close();
            }
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("error", ex.toString());
        }
        return image;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){
        view.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

the code is working fine if i use image directly from server in `listView` without downloading then for reuse but not after download it.

one more question, how do i know if image has downloaded and see them, i am using real device to run application.

Comment: atleast tell me, why -1 ?

Comment: FYI I didn't down vote. You should use image loading libraries like Glide, Picasso, Universal image loader for loading images. These libraries does a great job and are highly optimized for loading images

Comment: And your catch block is empty. You might be missing exception log why your offline thing is not working

Comment: yeah,i thought it too but there is not much images (3 - 4 images only) to load, that's why i am not using them.

Comment: then use your catch block to print the log.. Check if you are getting any exception

Comment: ok, here is error. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.nishant.book/files/-KoIyV6QfLGC3J0uMAwo.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found answer for this. actually i was bit confuse with `inputStream.read()` method, i thought it would read all the bytes from inputStream but i was wrong, `.read()` method only read `1 byte` then cursor goes to next `byte`, so i needed to use `while` method to read all data.

you can use a buffer there too.

Here is my code..

```
public class AvatarLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Context context;
    private ImageView view;
    private String userID;

    public AvatarLoader(Context context, ImageView view, String userID){
        this.view = view;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){
        Bitmap image = null;
        String fileName = userID + ".png";
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            if (inputStream == null){
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
                OutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                while((int oneByte = inputStream.read()) != -1){
                    outputStream.write((byte)oneByte);
                }
                outputStream.close();
            }
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("error", ex.toString());
        }
        return image;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){
        view.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated. But why not go for an image loading library instead such as Glide(google)/Picasso(squareup) for image loading purposes. These do abstract away many of the common issues that might come up while fetching images from network.

Comment: yeah, Glide or Picasso is good where fetching images from server is main feature of application like gallery app (there need to be many images fetched from server). but in my project there is only 4 - 6 images that need to load only very first time application run. so i thought to do it in this way and it went right.